# Assistance in creating Excel Macro that generates a new worksheet based off a template

Tags: excel, vba

I am extremely new to VBA - this is not a lazy attempt to get someone to do work for me and I am happy to be provided the tools to do this myself.

I have a worksheet consisting of data under specific column headers. I would like to create a macro that generates a new worksheet (in a totally new workbook) and copies the data from the original worksheet into the new workbook based on a pre-defined template. The column headers in the original worksheet will not match their respective column headers in the template. The data in each row consists of text, and both positive and negative numbers. When the data from the original worksheet is copied to the new workbook I would like each line to be separated by a completely blank row with this single caveat: each "blank" row must have a single number entry consisting of the same number in the populated row above it, but with its sign reversed (eg. if the original data contains -300 in Column E the blank row underneath must have +300 in Column E). All numbers will always/only ever be in one column (eg. Column E).

I hope this is enough information to get started!

Comment: I would build the template ready, then open it from the macro, copy & paste the relevant data then do save as on the template. Do not save the template as that would overwrite it. There are a couple of questions on here with code doing that.

Comment: An image of what you want would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreword: This isn't a complete answer but its too much text to write in a comment.

It sounds like you're looking to write a code using a [For Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) to copy a column of data using [Range.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy).

I don't have enough information to really write an example program but I cant guess the structure would look like this:

```
 Sub FillFromTemplate()
    Dim NewWB As Workbook, NewWS As Worksheet
    
    Set NewWB = Application.Workbooks.Add
    'Creates a new workbook
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=NewWB.Sheets(NewWB.Sheets.Count)
    'Copies the template over to the new workbook
    
    Set NewWS = NewWB.Sheets(NewWB.Sheets.Count)
    'Grabs our new sheet so we can edit the data
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Original").Columns("E").Copy Destination:=NewWS.Columns("E")
    'Copy over column E from the desired sheet to the new sheet.
    
    For i = 2 To NewWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row * 2 Step 2
    'iterate through the column on the new sheet, adding spaces
        NewWS.Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        'Somewhat inefficient, but simple and easy to implement.
        'A better but more complex method would be pasting the data while skipping cells
        
        If NewWS.Cells(i, "E") <> "" And IsNumeric(NewWS.Cells(i, "E")) Then
            'If its a number, put the value in the cell below with the sign flipped.
            NewWS.Cells(i + 1, "E") = NewWS.Cells(i, "E").Value * -1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Obviously this is missing critical information to run right away in your workbook. But I hope it is educational and can help you get started on writing code on your own.

Comment: Just to follow-up I inserted this code into my workbook and it works almost exactly as intended! Thank you so much. I am now working on a way to make sure the column headers in the original sheet do not replace the column headers in the new sheet (which are based on the template) when they are copied over.